# repeater inside another repeater with asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i have some queries with asp.net repeaters. The parent repeater is in an update panel. Child repeater contains a radio button within the item template. But, when i check any of the radio buttons within the child repeater, the page is fully posting back to the server instead of partial post back. Please help me by giving the solution.

Comment: Do you have any code available that you could post? It would be good to see what properties are set on the update panel (e.g. Triggers/ChildrenAsTriggers to rule those out).

Comment: Please add your markup.